# spark is not taking all of the index content

Tags: python, elasticsearch

i have an index that contains 6130057 raws 
well i set a condition at first to modify date format 
then loaded it to documents to a dataframe 
the problem is that it's only taking 10 raws in both documents and df i don't know why 
this is my code

````
from datetime import datetime as dt


def convert_ts(hit):
    hit = hit['_source']
# change Refill_Bar_End_Date_and_Time
    try:
        ts_from_doc = hit.get('Refill_Bar_End_Date_and_Time', None)

        if not ts_from_doc:
            raise ValueError('`Refill_Bar_End_Date_and_Time` not found')

        # incoming as millisec so convert to sec
        as_date = dt.fromtimestamp(
            int(ts_from_doc / 1000.0)
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        hit['Refill_Bar_End_Date_and_Time'] = as_date

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
# change Temporary_Service_Class_Expiry_Date
    try:
        ts_from_doc = hit.get('Temporary_Service_Class_Expiry_Date', None)

        if not ts_from_doc:
            raise ValueError('`Temporary_Service_Class_Expiry_Date` not found')

        # incoming as millisec so convert to sec
        as_date = dt.fromtimestamp(
            int(ts_from_doc / 1000.0)
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        hit['Temporary_Service_Class_Expiry_Date'] = as_date

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
# change Service_Fee_Expiry_Date
    try:
        ts_from_doc = hit.get('Service_Fee_Expiry_Date', None)

        if not ts_from_doc:
            raise ValueError('`Service_Fee_Expiry_Date` not found')

        # incoming as millisec so convert to sec
        as_date = dt.fromtimestamp(
            int(ts_from_doc / 1000.0)
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        hit['Service_Fee_Expiry_Date'] = as_date

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass 
# change Supervision_Period_Expiry_Date
    try:
        ts_from_doc = hit.get('Supervision_Period_Expiry_Date', None)

        if not ts_from_doc:
            raise ValueError('`Supervision_Period_Expiry_Date` not found')

        # incoming as millisec so convert to sec
        as_date = dt.fromtimestamp(
            int(ts_from_doc / 1000.0)
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        hit['Supervision_Period_Expiry_Date'] = as_date

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass  
# change Last_Service_Fee_Deduction_Date
    try:
        ts_from_doc = hit.get('Last_Service_Fee_Deduction_Date', None)

        if not ts_from_doc:
            raise ValueError('`Last_Service_Fee_Deduction_Date` not found')

        # incoming as millisec so convert to sec
        as_date = dt.fromtimestamp(
            int(ts_from_doc / 1000.0)
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        hit['Last_Service_Fee_Deduction_Date'] = as_date

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
# change Account_Disconnection_Date    
    try:
        ts_from_doc = hit.get('Account_Disconnection_Date', None)

        if not ts_from_doc:
            raise ValueError('`Account_Disconnection_Date` not found')

        # incoming as millisec so convert to sec
        as_date = dt.fromtimestamp(
            int(ts_from_doc / 1000.0)
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        hit['Account_Disconnection_Date'] = as_date

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
# change Credit_Clearance_Date   
    try:
        ts_from_doc = hit.get('Credit_Clearance_Date', None)

        if not ts_from_doc:
            raise ValueError('`Credit_Clearance_Date` not found')

        # incoming as millisec so convert to sec
        as_date = dt.fromtimestamp(
            int(ts_from_doc / 1000.0)
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        hit['Credit_Clearance_Date'] = as_date

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
# change Negative_Balance_Barring_Start_Date
    try:
        ts_from_doc = hit.get('Negative_Balance_Barring_Start_Date', None)

        if not ts_from_doc:
            raise ValueError('`Negative_Balance_Barring_Start_Date` not found')

        # incoming as millisec so convert to sec
        as_date = dt.fromtimestamp(
            int(ts_from_doc / 1000.0)
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        hit['Negative_Balance_Barring_Start_Date'] = as_date

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
# change Activation_Date
    try:
        ts_from_doc = hit.get('Activation_Date', None)

        if not ts_from_doc:
            raise ValueError('`Activation_Date` not found')

        # incoming as millisec so convert to sec
        as_date = dt.fromtimestamp(
            int(ts_from_doc / 1000.0)
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        hit['Activation_Date'] = as_date

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
# change Date
    try:
        ts_from_doc = hit.get('Date', None)

        if not ts_from_doc:
            raise ValueError('`Date` not found')

        # incoming as millisec so convert to sec
        as_date = dt.fromtimestamp(
            int(ts_from_doc / 1000.0)
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        hit['Date'] = as_date

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
    return hit


es = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:9200'], timeout=600)
documents = es.search(index='subscribers-20200101', body={})['hits']['hits']
documents = [convert_ts(doc) for doc in documents]

print(documents) 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(documents)
df.count() ```
the count shows
````

Account_Activated_Flag                    10
Account_Balance_Units                     10
Account_Disconnection_Date                 9
Account_Group_Id                          10
Account_ID_Master_MSISDN                  10
Account_In_Euro_Flag                      10
Activation_Date                            9
Community_Id_1                            10
Community_Id_2                            10
Community_Id_3                            10
Converged_Flag                            10
Credit_Clearance_Date                      9
Date                                      10
First_Call_Done_Flag                      10
First_IVR_Call_Done_Flag                  10
GPRS_Block_Status                         10
Language                                  10
Life_Cycle_Notification_Report            10
Low_Level_Warning_Played_Flag             10
Negative_Balance_Barred_Flag              10
Not_Used                                  10
Not_Used_2                                10
Original_Service_Class_ID                 10
Originating_SMS_Block_Status              10
Originating_Voice_Block_Status            10
Refill_Failed_Counter                     10
Service_Class_ID                          10
Service_Fee_Expiry_Date                    9
Service_Fee_Expiry_Flag                   10
Service_Fee_Expiry_Warning_Flag           10
Service_Fee_Period_Warning_Played_Flag    10
Service_Offerings                         10
Special_Announcement_Played_Flag          10
Subscriber_ID_MSISDN                      10
Supervision_Expiry_Flag                   10
Supervision_Expiry_Warning_Flag           10
Supervision_Period_Expiry_Date             9
Supervision_Period_Warning_Played_Flag    10
Temporary_Block_Flag                      10
Terminating_SMS_Block_Status              10
Terminating_Voice_Block_Status            10
dtype: int64 ```

Comment: i searched about this , i find out that it takes as default 10 hits , but how can i increase it to read all my raws ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ..

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

client = Elasticsearch()
s = Search(using=client, index="sub1")
s = s[1:]

def convert_ts(hit):
# change Refill_Bar_End_Date_and_Time
    try:
        ts_from_doc = hit.get('Refill_Bar_End_Date_and_Time', None)

        if not ts_from_doc:
            raise ValueError('`Refill_Bar_End_Date_and_Time` not found')

        # incoming as millisec so convert to sec
        as_date = dt.fromtimestamp(
            int(ts_from_doc / 1000.0)
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        hit['Refill_Bar_End_Date_and_Time'] = as_date

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass

    return hit

documents = ([hit.to_dict() for hit in s.scan()])
documents = [convert_ts(doc) for doc in documents]
df = pd.DataFrame(documents)
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this one

client = Elasticsearch()
s = Search(using=client, index="sub1")

df = pd.DataFrame([hit.to_dict() for hit in s.scan()])

but it's not taking the try exeption in considiration